# Upgrade error = API error: Value already exists in the database on ReportTemplate.create

Tags: drupal, upgrade

I've had the above error on a couple of upgrades recently - one was an upgrade to 5.57.3 on a test system and another when upgrading the 'Report Plus' extension (see below)[image]. In both cases the upgrade stopped but appeared to be successful. I looked at the code (attached) but couldn't figure out what the problem is. Both were Drupal 7 systems.  Can anyone help (please) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a recent version of CiviCRM you can run the Managed.reconcile api through the api explorer - in this instance I'm running it to reconcile extended reports - you can do all extensions at once, or one or two at a time. You are looking to see which extension hits an error while reconciling - the extension with the issue might not be the one that you are experiencing the error on.

[image: Managed_reconcile]

Generally all declared managed entities should have an entry in the `civicrm_managed` table - eg for this entity https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/blob/21b4be5d01384caf73ffe9c9e92f187d8f6cf84d/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.mgd.php I can find a row in civicrm_managed and the entity_id matches the id of the OptionValue in civicrm_option_value (note that `ReportTemplate` is a v3 api alias for `OptionValue` - & Extended report uses both at the moment as it is migrating to v4

[image: entity]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eileen, who said 'Generally you see that when there is an entry in civicrm_option_value but not in civicrm_managed for a report being registered by the extension & the site will keep getting the error until it is fixed'.  The culprit seemed to be an entry from the ReportPlus extension in civicrm_option_value that remained after I uninstalled this extension. This record had the label 'Activity Detail Plus'

Comment: Did you just delete the record 'Activity Detail Plus' and the error went away?

Comment: Neither of the 2 systems that had the extension were using any of the ReportPlus reports so I used uninstalling as a quick way of identifying mismatched items.  In both cases it was this 'Activity Detail Plus' record which I deleted.  I reran the 5.57.3 upgrade on one system and it then worked.  On the other system I believe that although the upgrade failed on the last step, it all worked & there's no damage.  If you didn't want to remove ReportPlus it would be worth deleting this record & retrying.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar error, is this related or a separate issue? In this case, the upgrade did not complete.
[image]

Comment: Looks exactly the same problem to me.

Comment: Keith actually at that stage of the upgrade, the upgrade *did* complete, but it is having a hard time loading the final update complete page due to the extension conflict. Check your civicrm_domain table in your MySQL and see what the version is.  If it is correct, you are OK.  Update the extension all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this. Fixed by disabling the Reports Plus extension (v 2.6.2) which we were attempting to use the same time as Extended Reports (v. 5.21) on CiviCRM 5.58.1

Answer (score 0):

I found my culprit with this method. What I also figured out is that when I disabled Mosaico there were many references left in the database and I got the "missing" error message. Ultimately I deleted every reference in my civicrm database and then the errors went away and now my site is clean. It seems that uninstalling and then deleting a specific extension does not remove all references ? That said, thank you for the api4 method to uncover a culprit Eileen.